# How to create a service that returns a unique instance for each call?

Tags: angular

Maybe angular have another solution?

I looked at the documentation and as I understand it is not possible in angular using Injectable. But what should I do in this case? Should I write a class and inherit from it or export it in the same way?
I'm afraid to write some crutches, so I would like to get any information on this matter.

I would be grateful for any information!

Comment: What I've done in the past is have a service that acts as a factory for whatever object type you want a new instance of on each use. i.e. your single factory instance creates the actual type you want.

Comment: That is to me to be inherited from it? I didn't quite understand what you mean by: i.e. your single factory instance creates the actual type you want.

Comment: Let's say you want an individual instance of class `A` in each of the components. You might make an Angular service called `AFactory` that has the method `getA()` that returns a new instance of `A`. In your component(s), you'd do something like:

`constructor(aFactory: AFactory) { this.aInstance = aFactory.getA(); }`

Comment: actual type - what does it look like?

Comment: i have class MediaRecorderService, i need use this? `getRecorder() {
  return MediaRecorderService
 }`

Comment: Yeah, for you, the service you would use is called something like `MediaRecorderFactory` which would have a method `getRecorder()` which would return `new MediaRecorderService()`

Comment: Here's an example: https://replit.com/@Christop406/DeterminedLazyIrcbot#index.ts

Comment: i can't get instance https://ibb.co/ypxHFKR

Comment: i have endless loading on example website

Answer (score 0):

You can add the injection token to the `providers` array to get a new instance:

```js
@Component({
  ...
  providers: [ MyService ],
})
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(public s: MyService) {}
}
```

Angular has hierarchical dependency injection. When you use an injection token in the constructor it searches up the hierarchy for a provider: https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ecas3n?file=src/app/app.module.ts